# VB / VBA StrComp or =

Tags: excel, string-comparison, vba

What, if anything, is the benefit of using

```
If StrComp(strVal1, strVal2, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
```

as opposed to using

```
If strVal1 = strVal2 Then
```

If `Option Compare Text` is set at the module level, is there any difference?

I know StrComp handles null scenarios and <> scenarios, I am only interested in the situation where strVal1 and strVal2 have non-null valid strings assigned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If `Option Compare Text` is set at the module level, is there any difference?

No. It simply offers a finer grained control (no module-level strategy commitments). However, if you *can* make such a commitment, go for the `x = y` option: less code is always better code.

Comment: less code is *always* better code? [code golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @MarkCh “… all other things being equal,” of course.

Comment: StrComp with vbBinaryCompare is way faster. `Whenever you can, use binary comparison. This is VB's default. Text comparison is much slower.` http://www.aivosto.com/vbtips/stringopt.html

Comment: @lpfx True, but that wasn’t the question here. The question was whether there was a difference between the two different methods of overriding the default — and there isn’t.

Comment: From @Barry-Jon question: `What, if anything, is the **benefit** of using...`

Comment: @lpfx He’s asking about “vb**Text**Compare”. And there is **no** benefit to using that over `a = b`.

Answer (score 2):

Since StrComp is comparing string (with cultural info), UpperCase and LowerCase are not taking care ... (so Hello is the same as hello). In the case of =, there will be different (Like using a Binary compare).
If option compare text is at module level, there will be no difference (but you should use StrComp in case another guy delete it)...