# Excel VBA StrCmp sub or function not defined

Tags: excel, excel-2007, strcmp, vba

I am trying to use the StrCmp function in excel vba (using excel 2007) and am getting the following error:
Compile Error:
Sub or Function Not Defined.

Here is my code:

```
    StrCmp(Worksheets(1).Range("I" & x).Value, "Critical")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functions name is `StrComp` and to call it you would say :
`StrComp( StringArg1, StringArg2, compareMethod) = 0` for a match.

It seems like in your case you would use

```
if StrComp(Cstr(Worksheets(1).Range("I" & x).Value), "Critical", vbTextCompare) = 0 then
    ' you now have found a match
    ' do something
end if
```

More on the [StrComp()](http://www.codevba.com/visual-basic-source-code/vb-string/checking_if_two_strings_are_equal.htm), also [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9s233cfc(v=vs.90).aspx) and also see this here on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756118/vb-vba-strcomp-or)