# VBA - String compare in 'If Else' statement giving me the wrong output in excel

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I'm sorry if I'm completely misunderstanding the use of StrComp I'm quite new to VBA. What I am trying to do is compare a cell with the cell above it in excel, to check if its the same string/text. If it is the same, then I'm wanting to display a 1 in excel to show its a repeat. If its different then 0. However, I appear to be getting 1 most of the time when it should be 0. The if else statement doesn't seem to be working. Anyone got an idea why this might be the case?

I have tried to put in msgbox to see if my rows/columns are wrong using the offsets, but this doesn't seem to be the case. I have a feeling I may be misunderstanding the use of StrComp.

```
Option Compare Text 

Sub IF_Loop()    
    Dim cell As Range    
    Dim InputRng As Range, checkRng As Range

    Set cell = ActiveCell    
    Set InputRng = Application.Selection     
    xTitleId = "duplicateSearch"

    Set checkRng = Application.InputBox("Title search :", xTitleId, Type:=8)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each cell In checkRng.Columns(1).Cells    
        If StrComp(cell.Value, cell.Offset(-1, 0)) Then    
            cell.Offset(0, -2).Value = 1    
        Else:    
            cell.Offset(0, -2).Value = 0    
        End If    
    Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: It might help to read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/strcomp-function) to understand the return values

Comment: use `Upper(cell.Value) = Upper(cell.Offset(-1, 0))`  Strcomp returns 3 values, -1 for less than, 0 for equals, 1 for greater than.

Comment: @ScottCraner - OP has `Option Compare Text` so `Upper` isn't needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `StrComp` [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/strcomp-function):

**Return Values**

| If | StrComp returns |
| --- | --- |
| *string1* is less *than string2* | -1 |
| *string1* is equal to *string2* | 0 |
| *string1* is greater than *string2* | 1 |
| *string1* or *string2* is **Null** | **Null** |

`StrComp` does not return a `Boolean`, so you have an implicit boolean conversion currently. When `StrComp` returns `0` for equality, the implicit boolean conversion (`Cbool(0)` = `False`) is your problem.

Check if the result `= 0`.

```
If StrComp(cell.Value, cell.Offset(-1, 0)) = 0 Then
```

Or since  you have `Option Compare Text` specified, [just use `=` to compare](https://stackoverflow.com/a/756136/9245853).

Comment: Thank you! That solved the problem! Was getting confused as you said. Went with the = to compare, which did the trick. Just out of curiosity, I've now noticed that if there is a slight variation on the end of a text such as a full stop, its treated as different, is there a way of ignoring something like that?

Comment: Perhaps nest a `Replace`?